# Remove VSTS Connection From Solution/Project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, source-control-explorer

How to remove vsts connection from a project. I copied a solution which had vsts connection. The copied solution too had connection with server. So I want to remove the vsts connection completely from the newly copied solution. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the solution folder. Remove the 2 hidden folders name .git, .vs and 2 files .gitattributes, .gitignore. Now open the solution. Now there is no vsts connection in the project/solution.